# How to check for empty request.FILE in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to submit a form even without uploading an image. But I got the error

```
**MultiValueDictKeyError**
```

This is my views.py

```
filepath = request.FILES['filepath']
```

Comment: Does my answer helped you ?

Comment: Andriy Ivaneyko yes.. it helps.. sorry for late response.. you give me three choice and i use the first one...

Comment: if it's answered your question could you accept it ?

Answer (score 23):

See how you can dial with that error:

1. Use the `MultiValueDict's` get method to access files.

   ```
   filepath = request.FILES.get('filepath', False)
   ```

   If no `filepath` in FILES, than `filepath` variable would be False.
2. One line assignment with  [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) operator:

   ```
   filepath = request.FILES['filepath'] if 'filepath' in request.FILES else False
   ```
3. (**Not reccomended**) Handle `MultiValueDictKeyError` exception like in code below:

   ```
   from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError

   try:
       filepath = request.FILES['filepath']
   except MultiValueDictKeyError:
       filepath = False
   ```

**Update**:
 As @Saysa pointed depanding of what steps youd should perform after getting `filepath` you need to choose which **default value** would be assigned to `filepath`, for instance if you have to handle case when `filepath` not present in `FILES` at all it's better to use `None` as default value and check condition as `if filepath is None` to identify filepath have been submitted, if you need to have some default value simply assign it...

In example above default value is `False` to make code  more apparent for you...

Comment: I wouldn't really advise `False` as a default value since that is a different type than the intended type

Comment: Agree, but anyway checking for `Falsy` or `is None` should be performed before working with `filepath` . 
@Sayse Or you mean that's better to assign `falsy` string `''`?

Comment: well `if None` would produce the same result as `if False`

Comment: @Sayse  i've updated my answer to give more info about default values assignment

Answer (score 2):

just as an add on to the posting. If you want to check the filepath is given I had to change the type to boolean like this:

```
if bool(request.FILES.get('filepath', False)) == True:
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `request.FILES.get('filepath')` so if no image then `filepath` should be `None`